# SKU Product name - edit product

Tags: product, admin, edit

I would like to add the SKU to the product name in "edit product" at the admin-side. Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.
Just copy `Edit.php` file from `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product` and paste into `local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product`

and find following function `public function getHeader()` and replace with this:

```
public function getHeader()
    {
        $header = '';
        if ($this->getProduct()->getId()) {

            $header = $this->escapeHtml($this->getProduct()->getSku() . " " .$this->getProduct()->getName());
        }
        else {
            $header = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Product');
        }
        if ($setName = $this->getAttributeSetName()) {
            $header.= ' (' . $setName . ')';
        }
        return $header;
    }
```

See the line: `$header = $this->escapeHtml($this->getProduct()->getSku() . " " .$this->getProduct()->getName());` where I have added `$this->getProduct()->getSku()`. This is giving you the sku of the product.

**For best practise you should follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43704/how-to-quickly-override-modify-core-block-file). Remember this only helps you on `magento core file override`.** This will make sure the upgrade will not have much affect on your site.
Hope this helps.